# Ubuntu 14.04 on HP Spectre 13-3000ed

Tags: 14.04, hardware, hp, compatibility

I am thinking of buying the HP Spectre 13-3000ed ultrabook and my question is: will it work with Ubuntu 14.04?

Specs:

- Intel Core i7-4500U 1.8-3.0GHz
- 13.3" WQHD (2560x1440) Glare + Touch
- 8192MB RAM
- 256GB SSD
- Intel HD 4400
- Bluetooth
- Windows 8
- Webcam
- 1.48Kg
- US QWERTY keyboard layout
- 1.5cm thick
- newest Wireless LAN: 802.11ac

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work, make sure to install the latest version 14.10 64 bits to use the 8GB of RAM, all hardware is compatible.